# Solr running on Https - SolrJ Connection issue

Tags: https, solr, solrj

Am running Solr in Https(8443) port on top of tomcat, How can i access that solr using solrj client, I can see only CommonsHttpSolrServer is availble,

Please suggest is there any way to access the https port enabled solr using SolrJ?.

Answer (score 5):

Solrj internally uses [Apache Http Client](http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/). When using `CommonsHttpSolrServer` it will create one & use it, if you are not providing it with one.

In this case since you need support for SSL you could provide your own SSL configured HttpClient to `CommonsHttpSolrServer` constructor. Check its  [API](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/api/index.html?org/apache/solr/client/solrj/impl/CommonsHttpSolrServer.html) that accepts HttpClient.

```java
CommonsHttpSolrServer(String solrServerUrl, HttpClient sslHttpClient, ...
```

You can see the following guide, on how to create SSL enabled http client [SSL Guide](http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/sslguide.html).

This should help.