# Solr - instantiate HttpSolrServer with Httpclient

Tags: java, solr, httpclient

I need to connect to our solr server which is behind a proxy(?).
Following I tried (nothing special):

```
SolrServer server = new HttpSolrServer("https://urltosolr/solr");
try {
    SolrPingResponse pingResponse = server.ping();
} catch (SolrServerException e) {
    ....
}
```

stacktrace:

```
 org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrServerException: IOException occured when talking to server at: https://urltosolr/solr
 ...
 Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: peer not authenticated
```

After that I tried the other constructor for HttpSolrServer but I don't know how to set username and password correctly into HttpClient. Can anyone help?

Comment: Possibly related to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9068759/solr-running-on-https-solrj-connection-issue

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't see where you're trying to connect through a proxy in your code, you only provided the solr url while creating the `HttpSolrServer`. You can provide your own `HttpClient` instance while [creating](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/api-3_6_0/org/apache/solr/client/solrj/impl/HttpSolrServer.html#HttpSolrServer%28java.lang.String,%20org.apache.http.client.HttpClient%29) your `HttpSolrServer` instance.  Your `HttpClient` instance can contain the information about the proxy. The needed code should be the following, which you can find in the [http-components examples](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/examples.html):

```
DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpHost proxy = new HttpHost(proxyHost, proxyPort, "http");
httpclient.getParams().setParameter(ConnRoutePNames.DEFAULT_PROXY, proxy);
httpclient.getCredentialsProvider().setCredentials(
                    AuthScope.ANY,
                    new UsernamePasswordCredentials(username, password));
SolrServer solrServer = new HttpSolrServer(solrUrl, httpclient);
```

Looking more at your question, I don't think you need to connect using a proxy. You error is  about https. Have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2308774/httpget-with-https-sslpeerunverifiedexception) other question and answers to see what you need to do. The version of httpclient you need to look at is 4.x.