# Solrj with HTTPS Security

Tags: ssl, solr, https, solrj

My Solr Server is SSL protected. Hence when I hit a query from Solrj I get following error
javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: peer not authenticated or unauthorized access.

So, I have used this link - 
http://java.dzone.com/articles/using-solrj-basic

However, it still gives me gives me 
SocketConnectionEXception:connection reset error

Please suggest me methods to use Solrj with ssl wrapped server

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Does [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9069291/326543) help?

Comment: I tried this link but still face same issue :(